# jquery function for getting image of preview image

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having a code for creating a preview of image using jquery..
well that is working fine.. but the problem comes when i want the height and width of that preview image..

here is my jquery function..

```
$(function() {
    $('.cvrupload').change(function(){
        cvrpre(this);   
        var newfl_h = $('.cvr').find("img").height(), 
        newfl_w = $('.cvr').find("img").width();
        alert(newfl_h); // this line does not show any height, it shows null
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function cvrpre(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('.cvr').attr('src', e.target.result);
          }

       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

if i use `$('.cvr').height()` instead of `$('.cvr').find("img").height()` then it gives the height of previous image which was in `$('.cvr')`

Comment: Tell us what the problem *is*, as well as where it comes

Comment: @oGeez, i want height and width of previewed image..

Comment: Is the image being changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is, that the code goes on before your `cvrpre` function is finished. you should return width and height within your cvrpre function. so it would work